# Java streams: collect to map creating two keys for each stream element

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Java stream that invokes `.collect(Collectors.toMap)`. `Collectors.toMap` accepts a `keyMapper` and a `valueMapper` functions. I'd like to create two entries for each stream element, with two different `keyMapper` functions, but with the same `valueMapper` function. Is it possible to do this in a nice stream syntax without creating a custom collector?

Of course, I could also get one map, then add another set of keys with the same values to it, outside of the stream chain calls. But I was wondering if it could be made neater...

Basically what I have is:

```
List<A> someObjects = ...; // obtain somehow
Map<String, B> res = someObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(keyMapper1, valueMapper));
```

And functions `keyMapper1` and `keyMapper2` produce different strings, and I want both of those in my map with the same value.

What I can do is:

```
Map<A, B> map = someObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), valueMapper));
Map<String, B> result = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((a, b) -> {
    result.put(keyMapper1(a), b);
    result.put(keyMapper2(a), b);
});
```

But maybe something could be done without creating an intermediate variable?

Comment: Before you have `forEach` you can call `map` and return List of 2 elements (Pair) with defined keys (via mappers) and same value(value mapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to create a stream of all the map entries first, and then collect them to a map. Something like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = someObjects.stream()
    .flatMap(obj -> Stream.of(
            Map.entry(keyMapper1(obj), valueMapper(obj)),
            Map.entry(keyMapper2(obj), valueMapper(obj))))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Since Java 9: `Map.entry(...)`.